# missing the rails gem, redmine install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

i'm installing redmine and getting an error, i've commented out the version so it could use any that would load, I originally left it at version 2.3.5 with no luck

Missing the Rails gem. Please `gem install -v= rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

here is my gem list

$gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.0, 2.3.5)
builder (2.1.2)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the rails gem in the global gem store. If you just install the gem as a non-root user, it will be installed inside your $HOME/.gems directory. If you run Redmine as another user, it will not find that gem of course.

So you could just try to install the rails gem into the global gem store as root using

```
sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.5
```